# javascript distribution of inputs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do 2 things:

1. Balance out 3 inputs into 100

   ```
   $input1 = $('#input1 ');
   $input2 = $('#input2 ');
   $input3 = $('#input3 ');

   $input1.on('input', function () {
           $input2 .val(100 - this.value);
           $input3 .val(100 - this.value -  $input2.value)
   });
   ```

   `$input2` is displayed well yet doesn't output into `$input3` (NaN).

   I also tried to create a callback for input3 and that didn't work out well either.
2. How to block the input from showing numbers out of the range of 0-100.

[Here's a JSF](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/464720/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get rid of jQuery because you are confusing both the DOM API and jQuery API. The DOM is what you should learn, not jQuery.

```js
let $input1 = document.querySelector('#input1');
let $input2 = document.querySelector('#input2');
let $input3 = document.querySelector('#input3');

$input1.addEventListener('input', function () {
            $input2.value = (100 - this.value)/2;
            $input3.value = 100 - this.value -  $input2.value;
        });
```

```html
<form>
<input id='input1'/><br/>
<input id='input2'/><br/>
<input id='input3'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$input2` is a jQuery wrapped element. You cannot call `value` on it directly. You need to get the value using `val()` instead. Since `value` will return `undefined`, the final output is `NaN`.

Change this:

```
$input3.val(100 - this.value - $input2.value)
```

to this:

```
$input3.val(100 - this.value - $input2.val())
```

Alternatively, you can get the native element out of the jQuery wrapper and call `value` on it. The following should work seamlessly as well:

```
$input3.val(100 - this.value - $input2[0].value)
```

For #2, you may want to look into `input[type=number]` and restrict the range using `min` and `max` attributes.

Comment: thx, but none of your methods displays for input 3, it remains 0

Comment: @erezt -- Do you mean that none of the methods work? If so, you need to check your console for errors.

Comment: val() solved NaN, yet input 3 remains 0 and doesn't distribute the remainder of 100 minus the 2 inputs.

Comment: JSF is in question

Comment: @erezt -- Please see the other answer for solving #2. You have logical error in your code.

Answer (score 1):

As in other answer by @31piy you need to use `$input2.val()` or `$input2[0].value`. And balancing of values in field `input2` and `input3` can be done as below.

```js
$input1 = $('#input1 ');
$input2 = $('#input2 ');
$input3 = $('#input3 ');

$input1.on('input', function() {
  $input2.val(parseInt((100 - this.value) / 2));
  $input3.val(100 - this.value - $input2.val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" type=number min="0" max="100">
<input id="input2" type=number min="0" max="100">
<input id="input3" type=number min="0" max="100">
```